# How can I get grails remoteFunction to work?

Tags: javascript, grails, groovy

I have the following code in my gsp

```
<select onChange="${remoteFunction(action:'superior', controller:'employee', params: '\'name=\' + this.value')}">
    <option>first</option>
    <option>second</option>
</select>
```

To be specific, this code is in my _form.gsp file. The action in the EmployeeController is as follows:

```
    def superior() {
    println 'in here'
    println 'these are the params: ' + params
}
```

It probably seems nonsensical, but my goal here is just to be able to call my remote action and pass the selected value. But I see nothing being printed to the console. If I type the URL directly as follows

```
app-name/employee/superior
```

I see my print statements on the output. So what am I missing here? I basically followed how to set this up from the grails documentation (http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Tags/remoteFunction.html) and I have the JQuery plugin.
If I use a simple javascript function on the onChange event (such as an alert) it works fine. So I'm sure my browser does not have javascript turned off, I've tested this with several browsers actually. 
I'm pretty sure its something very simple I'm missing. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me this snippet is working perfectly in firefox and chrome. So I guess you have a general javascript error on your page. Check this with firebug. If there is no error, double check the generated code for the onchange tag of your select box.

Comment: I checked the javascript with firebug, I did not see an error. This is the generated javascript for the onchange `jQuery.ajax({type: "POST", data: "name=" + this.value, url: "/myapp/employee/superior", success: function (data, textStatus) {}, error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {}});` To test this I actually created an entirely new grails app, created the employee domain class with just a first and last name then generated the views and controllers. Then I pasted the select code block into my _form.gsp and the action into my controller and tested. Did I miss a step?

Comment: Has an HTTP request happened? Can you check using firebug? If there is one, then you will see it in the console tab.

Comment: Thanks for that tip. Firebug was saying "JQuery not defined" So I looked around online for others with a similar error. I had to add the following to the head section of my main.gsp file. `<g:javascript library="jquery" plugin="jquery" />` then I saw my output on the console. So thanks for helping me debug from another perspective, I was only debugging from my source.